# Python | How to show 2 models information in template with the same class

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to get 2 models information in template. Because there are Stations that has Devices. (I need to show Station detail with device list) How can I show 2 models information in template?

```
class StationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Station
    model = Device
    template_name = "station/detail_station.html"
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this link on how to add extra context (model) to a detail view class from the django documentaion
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context

```
class StationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Station
   
    template_name = "station/detail_station.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the Device
        context['device_list'] = Device.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks. But question: DetailView shows a Station details, how can i do if a want to show device with filtering sation id? (same sation that DetailView) Device.object.filter(station=...) Thanks.